# PHP CSV VLookup

Tags: php, arrays, csv, search, vlookup

I'm looking a PHP function that can read a CSV file and perform a vlookup on column 1 to echo the relating value on the same row in column 2.

For example, if the CSV contains:

```
Name,Email
John,john@domain1.com
Frank,frank@domain2.com
Julie,julie@domain3.com
```

I would like to lookup against a Name and echo the email value.

Something like:

```
<?php
$name = "Name to be inserted";
$csv = 'filename.csv';

*function to vlookup $name in $csv, get column 2 value and pipe to $email* 

echo $email;
?>
```

Can anyone suggest a function that can accomplish the above?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('test.csv'));
$findName="Frank";
foreach($csv as $values)
{
  if($values[0]==$findName)   // index 0 contains the name
    echo $values[1];          // index 1 contains the email  
}
```

Please note that the indexes used in this answer are specific to the csv format you gave. You will have to adjust the indexes if format changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

//Name,Email
//John,john@domain1.com
//Frank,frank@domain2.com
//Julie,julie@domain3.com

// Function Definition
function getEmailFromCSV($csv_name, $name) {
$file = fopen($csv_name, "r");

while (!feof($file)) {
    $arr = fgetcsv($file);
    if ($arr[0] == $name) {
        echo $arr[1];
    }
}
fclose($file);
}

// Function Calling
getEmailFromCSV('abc.csv', 'John');

// Input : John
// Output : john@domain1.com

?>
```