# PHP Vlookup Scripts

Tags: php, csv, vlookup

I have below script which work like as a vlookup() in Excel.

But in this I want to get data which match to csv.

There are different scripts I have created but both are not working.

### Script 1

```
$output = fopen("/var/www/outputfile.csv", 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('Entity ID', 'Part Number', 'New Title', 'New Description','Model Info'));

function checkpartnumber($entity_id,$partno,$output) {
    $source  = fopen("/var/www/Encompass_new_data.csv", 'r');
    $counter = 0;
    while (!feof($source)) {
        $arr = fgetcsv($source);
        $psdata = str_replace("'","",$partno);
        $encompasspart = str_replace("'","",$arr[0]);
        if ($encompasspart == $psdata) {
            echo $psdata . "\n";
            fputcsv($output, array($entity_id,$psdata,$arr[2],$arr[3],$arr[4] ));
        }
    }
    fclose($source);
}

$destination  = fopen("/var/www/PS_Remote_Data.csv", 'r');
while($data = fgetcsv($destination)){
    foreach($data as $pspartnumber)
    {
            $entity_id = $pspartnumber[0];
            $partno = $pspartnumber[1];
            checkpartnumber($entity_id,$partno,$output);
    }
}
```

### Script 2

```
$source  = fopen("/var/www/Tickets/14674/03 October/Encompass_Remote_Data.csv", 'r');
$destination = array_map('str_getcsv', file('/var/www/Tickets/14674/03 October/Remote_Data.csv'));

$output = fopen("/var/www/Tickets/14674/03 October/outputfile.csv", 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('Entity ID', 'Part Number', 'SKUCode', 'Title','URL','Vendor','New Title', 'New Description','Model Info'));
$counter = 0;
//if($counter > 0){
while ($data = fgetcsv($source)) 
{
        $partnumber= ltrim("'",$data[0]);
        $newtitle = trim($data[2]);
        $description = trim($data[3]);
        $modelinfo = trim($data[3]);
        foreach($destination as $value)
        {
                $value[1] = ltrim("'",$value[1]);
                if($value[1]==$partnumber) 
                {
                 echo $value[0] . "\n";
                 fputcsv($output, array($value[0],$partnumber,$value[2],$value[3],$value[4],$value[5],$newtitle,$description,$modelinfo));
                }
        }
}
```

I have create this script with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498765/php-csv-vlookup)

I want to search source file part number into destination file and copy source and destination file columns into new csv file if both part files part numbers match.

### Source File Columns

```
Entity_id   Part Number
13789832    70148018
13789901    01T25013Y08
13789907    AA59-10015R
13789960    01T45518Y01
13790021    PQ10779M-12
13790123    01T55446Y01
```

### Destination File Columns

```
Part Number Title   Description Model Information
01E40601S01 Alpine Assembly Remocon/ex-10   Alpine Assembly Remocon/ex-10   <table width='100%'><tr><td>EX10</td></table>
01T25013Y08 Alpine Remote Control Dva5205   Alpine Remote Control Dva5205   <table width='100%'><tr><td>DVA5205</td><td>DHAS680</td></table>
01T25688Y02 Alpine Remote Control   Alpine Remote Control   <table width='100%'><tr><td>DVA5200</td></table>
01T35478Y05 Alpine Remote Cont Nven852a (Ru Alpine Remote Cont Nven852a (Ru <table width='100%'><tr><td>NVEN851A</td><td>NVEN852A</td><td>PKG700A</td></table>
01T45518Y01 Alpine Remote Control Rue4187.  Alpine Remote Control Rue4187.  <table width='100%'><tr><td>CDA7873</td><td>CDA7876</td><td>CDA7878</td><td>CDA7892</td></tr><tr><td>CVA1003</td></table>
01T55446Y01 Alpine Assembly Remocon Rue4190 Alpine Assembly Remocon Rue4190 <table width='100%'><tr><td>IVAD900</td><td>IVAD901</td></table>
```

---

I want to search Source file Part number into Destination csv file if it matches then **entity_id** from source file and `Part Number`    `Title`
    `Description`   and `Model Information` from destination file should be copy to output csv file.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by `if both part files part numbers match` Where is this other part number you are trying to match against

Comment: if partnumber from source file matches to partnumber destination file.

Comment: Ah thats what it looks like you are doing. So what is actually not happening as you want it to. Maybe it would be useful to see a sample of these 2 files. Add samples to your question dont put in a comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please check updated question